# How put PHP and HTML code iike text inside javascript var. (innerHTML)?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I would like put my code to javascript var like that :

```
function myFunction(){

var switch = document..(etc..)....style.backgroundcolour;

var somethink2 = 'red';      <----- I tell about it

switch = somethink2;

}
```

and after that my background colour will be switch after using function.

I can"t do that with PHP code (my code connection with sql database) becouse i have not got a " and '.

"dane" (in getElementByID()) in my code below is  and i want put this PHP code inside this div.

Guys please help me :)

Regards!

```
function swap(){
 var zawartosc =


 <?php $a4="SELECT silnik FROM marki WHERE model = 'A4'"; 

 $result2 = mysqli_query($connection,$a4);
 echo "<br>";
 echo "<table border='1'>";                 // I WANT PUT THIS LIKE A TEXT
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
     echo "<tr>";
     foreach ($row as $field => $value) { 
         echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>"; 
     }
     echo "</tr>";
 }
 echo "</table>";
 ?>

 document.getElementById("dane").innerHTML = zawartosc;
}
```

Comment: `var somethink2 = '<?php echo $var;?>';`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Don't forget about JavaScript escaping.

Comment: But i have problem inside line like that: <?php $a4="SELECT silnik FROM marki WHERE model like 'A4' ";   and when i use to much " and ' and i cant do it :(

Comment: You can also put arbitrary data inside your HTML using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) so that your JavaScript can retrieve this data and use it for whatever purpose you have in mind. This separation is often cleaner than PHP writing JavaScript.

Comment: Use `HEREDOC` instead of `"` or `NOWDOC` instead of `'`   See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc  This is too abstract for an answer, IE you dont have enough code to know how to do it.

Comment: Do you want to put the whole tables HTML in JS?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
 $a4="SELECT silnik FROM marki WHERE model = 'A4'"; 

 $result2 = mysqli_query($connection,$a4);
 $html = [];

 $html[] = "<br>";
 $html[] = "<table border='1'>";                 // I WANT PUT THIS LIKE A TEXT


 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
     $html[] = "<tr>";
     foreach ($row as $field => $value) { 
         $html[] = "<td>" . $value . "</td>"; 
     }
     $html[] = "</tr>";
 }
 $html[] = "</table>";

 $html = json_encode($html); //'["<br>","<table border='1'>", ...]'
 ?>

 document.getElementById("dane").innerHTML = <?php echo $html;?>.join("\n"); //no quotes needed
 //document.getElementById("dane").innerHTML = ["<br>","<table border='1'>", ...].join("\n");
```

Or you can just handle it like a normal string, but it's not what I would prefer to do.

```
 $html = implode($html);
 ?>

 document.getElementById("dane").innerHTML = "<?php echo $html;?>"; //careful with quotes here
```

In other words, don't output from PHP directly, instead build an array. It's much cleaner as you can consolidate that into a single variable and then use it.

For example:

```js
//timeout for demonstration purposes
setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById("dane").innerHTML = [
     "<br>",
      "<table border='1'>",
         "<tr>",
             "<td>foo</td>",
              "<td>bar</td>",
         "</tr>",
         "<tr>",
             "<td>biz</td>",
              "<td>baz</td>",
         "</tr>",
      "</table>"
  ].join("\n");
},500);
```

```css
table{width:100px;}
```

```html
<div id="dane"></div>
```

I like using `join` (it's like implode) for multi line strings in JS (even in my plugins).  In this case it works well with `json_encode`.

Basically we convert that array of HTML into a JSON string, which becomes a real Array in JS, then we let JS do the `imploding` with `join`.  Mainly because arrays don't require the use of a quote, so this avoids any issues if we have quotes in our html.

Consider this (using just strings):

```
<?php  
//HEREDOC
$html = <<<HTML
     <table border='1' style="color:red;" >
HTML;  
?> 
document.getElementById("dane").innerHTML = '<?php echo $html;?>'; 
document.getElementById("dane").innerHTML = "<?php echo $html;?>";
```

Which becomes this:

```
 document.getElementById("dane").innerHTML = '<table border='1' style="color:red;">'; //syntax error
 document.getElementById("dane").innerHTML = "<table border='1' style="color:red;">"; //syntax error
```

From what I see you can get away with `"` at the moment, but if you put them in your HTML, you'll probably be in trouble (if your just using strings).  Using join avoids this

```
 document.getElementById("dane").innerHTML = ["<table border='1' style=\"color:red;\">"].join("\n"); //json_encode knows how to escape " for json.
```

Hope it helps!